# Some Log messages not showing up

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

It seems that many Log calls are silently swallowed from my App. It took me a while to find out the problem is actually the Log not showing, because usually, when a Log message does not appear, I presume the method was not called.

However, I tried [isLoggable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable) and it told me that logging is disabled for this particular tag and level. I have many Log calls that just never show up, and sometimes they are on the same tag and level, it's like there's a completely random pattern of what logs and what doesn't.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063164/logcat-not-showing-debug-level-messages) ask suggests I should explicitly set the tag to `VERBOSE`, but I have more than one device and there's many tags with this problem.

Can't I just tell android "Give me all Logs on all Tags of this app"?