# Log.d not showing log.d in Logcat Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Android studio does not show any Logs I wrote in my code. I have tried putting the log to verbose and debug. I am using 'No filters'. Why is 'Oncreatetestlog' not showing up in my logcat?

```
package com.example.keydown;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d("Oncreatetestlog", "onCreate() Restoring previous state");
            /* restore state */
        } else {
            Log.d("Oncreatetestlog2", "onCreate() No saved state available");
            /* initialize app */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you select the right option in amdroid studio?

Comment: `if (savedInstanceState != null)` did you put anything into the savedInstanceState to make it not null?

Comment: @Minhtdh Well there's an else, so it should always show something.

Comment: @MohammedAtif What do you mean with right option?

Comment: There are many options on the left side of the logcat, tweeking them sometimes stops the logcat temporarily

Comment: can you post the screenshot of fullscreen logcat?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063164/logcat-not-showing-debug-level-messages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After hours of searching and trying, I found out it did not have to do with Android Studio, but that my phone didn't allow Logging. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app) for more information.

Answer (score 18):

Go to File -> invalidate caches / Restart. And let Android Studio index your project again. It works for me.

Comment: I tried, when I search the logcat for 'Oncreatetestlog' it doesn't show anything. Still not writing.

Comment: This helped me when new logging was making no effect on Android Emulator..

Comment: For anyone coming back to this: modify the filters. Mine was set to firebase for some reason, which *sometimes* but not always hides your messages. Not sure why.

Answer (score 9):

If Log.d is not showing in your Logcat just replace `Log.d` with `Log.wtf` Like this:

Replace:

```
Log.d("tag",""+catstr);
```

With:

```
Log.wtf("tag",""+catstr);
```

It Works..happy coding;)

Comment: I swear I thought this StackOverflow answer was a joke. IT IS NOT! It really did work for me. Never figured out why Log.d stopped logging for me, but this works great!

Comment: You did not explain why Log.d did not work.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could use `System.out.println()` to show the text in logcat

Replace

```
Log.d("Oncreatetestlog", "onCreate() Restoring previous state");
```

With

```
System.out.println("Oncreatetestlog onCreate() Restoring previous state");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check in "Run" on the right side of "Debug" on the bottom of the IDE.
in my case i actually did everything what they told but yet it's not working. so i checked there and i fount all the log over there.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to click on "Restart Logcat" btn located at left sidebar in logcat panel and it started showing all the logs. I hope it will help someone else too :D

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Fire tablets and Fire TV Stick do not show debug and verbose messages by default. You can enable them using ADB:

```
adb shell setprop persist.log.tag V
```

See [Set Android minimum log level globally (for all tags!)](https://medium.com/@mike_87757/set-android-minimum-log-level-globally-for-all-tags-4b1cbc1dc71f)