# Verbose and Debug logs not shows up in logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I just got a new Sony Xperia XA and found a strange issue on this device. It's not showing any Verbose and Debug logs. I tried every setting in Android Studio, used adb logcat to check if Android Studio is just filtering them. I even used different cables. I'm out of ideas, please help me.

Comment: Seems a duplicated question, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063164/logcat-not-showing-debug-level-messages

Comment: It is not duplicate. I have the same issue. This is new on Sony XA series with Android 7. There isn't seem to be any way to enable Debug logs so far

Answer (score 0):

You could try Wireless ADB(root)..